# Sonar Build error after Sonar version upgrade

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

We have recently upgrade our sonar Dev server Following are the details of the same:

Sonar server : 4.5.2 to 5.6.3,
C# plugin : 3.3 to 5.3.2
Sonar runner (sonar scanner) : 2.4 to 2.8

Post-upgrade, our XAML build is getting partially succeeded error. Warning is

> 15:05:30.046 WARN: * Use MSBuild 14 to get the best analysis results *
>
> 15:05:30.046 WARN: * The use of MSBuild 12 or the sonar-scanner to analyze C# projects is DEPRECATED * 15:05:30.046 WARN:

We are using MSBuild version 14.0 but still showing this warning
Regards
Dushyant Padhya